# How to redirect a sorted list of files returned by GNU find to a GUI file manager such as Nautilus or Dolphin

Tags: command-line, find, io-redirection, file-manager

## Question

I often fall in this situation where I have meticulously forged the perfect `find` command that returns exactly the ordered list of files I need to use. However, I cannot simply click on files to open or rename them. Ideally, I wish I could have this list as a view (in the spirit of the database views) so I could work with them easily as if they were altogether in the same directory.

There is two level of operations I wish I could do:

- first is simpler: show them in a file manager to open, move, delete, and rename
- second seems harder and may rely on filesystem mechanisms: create a view such that I could browse this view as any other directory

## File manager for list of files

Suppose a command that returns a sorted list of file in a proper format, is there a program that could take that list as input and provide the standard features expected in a file manager such as rename, move, and delete. I thought about something similar to Nautilus and Dolphin where I could scroll throughout the list and interactively select files and perform operations on them.

Another essential feature of graphical file manager are thumbnails when browsing through large collection of media. For instance, pictures which usually have irrelevant names. However, for this very specific case where I have only pictures, I already know dedicated programs such as 'Gthumb'.

## Simple use case: File Manager

For example, I have a command that return the list of all files sorted by modified time under the current directory:

```bsh
find "$(pwd)" -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td_%TH:%TM:%TS %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

which return one file with absolute path per line:

```
/tmp/file1
/tmp/dir1/file2
/tmp/dir1/file3
/tmp/dir2/file4
/tmp/dir1/file5
/tmp/file6
...
```

I wish I could display this list in this order and then rename some of them, drag'n'drop to move them to other directory, or simply open one.

## Complex use case: Views

Suppose the same command as above but this time I really want to create a view on this list of files, for instance some kind of fake directory containing this exact list of file. Such that I can open any program that operates on files and directories (emacs, nautilus... ) and go through these files. However, I don't want to work on links or copies of these files because I may want to work not only on their content but on the files themselves (move, delete, rename).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks more like a feature request than a true question that can have a useful answer.

Comment: @xenoid If I ask more specifically about which kind of software can take a list of file and displays them as a file manager does, would it be better? I can scrap the things about views that might be confusing.

Comment: Then there is a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site on SE for this.

Comment: Since a file manager is typically folder-oriented, I don't think it would help you, even if you could pass the list of files to it. The find command, IMO, is used to do the same thing to every selected file. For example: `find ... | xargs xdg-open`

Comment: @xenoid ok thanks for the pointer to Software Recommendations

Comment: @glennjackman I understand that usual file manager are not fitted to my needs however I expected that some other softwares could be. Also I know that some fancy terminals allows a bit of interactivity with the output of the shell commands eg. eshell in emacs does a little bit. I will investigate more in this direction.